# Magit: Prevent commit message from being pre-populated with a bullet point and file name

Tags: magit

Right now an example git commit message looks like below. It has the filename listed `* emacs.d/robenkleene/config/robenkleene-config.el:`. How do I not have the commit message pre-populated with that line? (Everything prefixed with a `#` is fine, it's just the one line listing the filename that will actually appear as part of the commit message that I want to never appear by default in commit messages.)

```
* emacs.d/robenkleene/config/robenkleene-config.el: 

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   emacs.d/robenkleene/config/robenkleene-config.el
#
```

Comment: I don't see it happen here, you must have some customization that causes this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It definitely might be a customization on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I was using `C`, to start a commit which fires `magit-commit-add-log`, which I guess means also include this entry. The correct commit binding to use is `c c`, which starts a commit without the file entry.

Comment: Yeah, it really means add that entry to the current commit message, if there is no current commit message then it starts a commit first.